# We can define the derivative of a function whose domain is a subset of rational numbers?

Tags: derivatives, definition

Usually the derivative is defined for a function $f:A\to \mathbb{R}$ where $A \subset \mathbb{R}$, and the usual definition of the derivative at a point $a$ require the existence of an open neighborhood of $a$ where the function is defined.

So, if $A\subset \mathbb{Q}$ it seems that we cannot define a derivative, since $A$ is totally disconnected.

But the definition

$$
f'(a)=\lim_{h \to 0}\dfrac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}
$$

require only the existence of the limit that, with the $\epsilon -\delta$ definition, can be found using only rational values of $h$.

So it seams that a ''derivative'' can be defined. Or there is something that does not works?

---

This question is suggested by [Clarification if a disconnected function has a derivative at defined points.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1505126/clarification-if-a-disconnected-function-has-a-derivative-at-defined-points) , where the OP asks for the derivability of the function
$$
f:\{x=\dfrac{n}{2k+1} | n,k \in \mathbb{Z}\} \to \mathbb{R} \quad;\quad f(x)=(-2)^x
$$

Comment: The derivative can be defined, using the normal definition you exhibit but with $h$ constrained to $\mathbb{Q}$; however, the limit may exist as a real but but might be irrational. So it's maybe a not very fruitful notion.

Comment: Well, so the function that I've added is a differentiable function? This sound strange to me....

Comment: Frankly, it sounds strange to me too. The function exhibited is real-valued ($f(\frac 1 3) = (-2)^{\frac 1 3}$) not rational-valued, never mind its odd domain. As I said, the definition makes sense, but it's... not much fun to work with.

Comment: @BrianO I found a helpful suggestion to your answer.

Comment: @EmilioNovati Hopefully this could help with your answer.

Comment: Thank You @Arbuja ! I've to better study your answer, but, if I well understand, if we chose as domain of the function the set $\{x=\frac{2n}{2k+1}: n,k \in \mathbb{Z} \}$ than the function is differentiable. It's right?

Comment: I think it is possible but I'm not sure.

Comment: @BrianO I heard from a professor that I can convert ${(-2)}^{x}$ into a complex function and then define the derivative at a real defined point. Is this true?

Comment: @Arbuja Of course. The log function can be defined in the whole complex plane minus a ray. Find the details in any complex analysis textbook. Pick your favorite value for log(-2) and get an analytic continuation.

Comment: @AlgRev Is it possible you can show me this? Otherwise I will be sure to buy one later.

Comment: @AlgRev Is there a source online?

Comment: @Arbuja see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm for a brief introduction. And here is a value you can take for $\log (-2)$: $\log (-2)=\log (-1)+\log 2=\pi i+\log 2$. So $(-2)^x=\exp (\log (-2)x)= \exp ((\pi i+\log 2)x )$

Comment: Okay I got the derivative as ${\left({\pi}{i}+\ln(2)\right)}{e}^{{\pi}*{i}+\ln{(2)}}={\left({-1}\right)}^{x}{2^x}\left({\pi}*{i}+\ln{(2)}\right)$ now how to I convert this to a real function.

Comment: @AlgRev Look at above

Comment: Of course you can define it.  Whether you call such a function "differentiable" is entirely a matter of taste; you should call it whatever you find it useful to call it, as long as you explain your definitions to others.

Comment: @EricWofsey: Thank you for the comment. But, does have some sense to define ''differentiability'' for a function whose domain is totally disconnected? there is some result about such kind of ''derivative'' or some reference that you know?

Comment: Possible answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1532619/derivative-definition-vs-its-requirements-for-existence

Comment: @EmilioNovati: Well, whether it makes sense to define it depends on what you want to use the definition for.  Some theorems about differentiable functions (such as the mean value theorem) will fail for this definition, and others will still work.  I don't know of any reference that discusses any of this directly, but you could try working through the section on differentiation in any real analysis text and see which parts work and which parts don't in this context.

Comment: @Arbuja: Thank you! It seems that you too are interested in such question! I suspect that the key fact here is that differentiability imply continuity, so there is some topological obstruction to well define a differentiable function on a totally disconnected set. But I'm not able to find exactly where is the obstruction.

Comment: I need someone to check for my post that I found the derivative.

Comment: @EmilioNovati I edited my answer. It can be defined only if $\{h=\frac{2n}{2k+1}: n,k \in \mathbb{Z} \}$ in $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)_f(x)}{h}$.

Comment: Since noone mentioned this yet... $\mathbb{Q}$ is not a Banach space. Differentiation in non-Banach spaces lack a lot of fruitful theorems (for instance, the Inverse Function Theorem). 

Also, as Eric said, lacking the mean value theorem is a bad thing.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo Perhaps you can check my post/answer and Mirko's comments below for the standard definition $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$.For most of the theorems the derivative does not exist but Mirko also believes that the derivative of ${(−2)}^{x}$ doesn't exist for the standard definition.

Comment: Is there anyone else willing to check my answer.

Comment: So I finally came to the conclusion that the derivative of $\left(-2\right)^{x}$ does not exist but it can exist for $|\left({-2}\right)^{x}|$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no reason that a derivative couldn't be defined on such a set like $\mathbb Q$. As you note, the limit
$$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(h)}{h}$$
may still be calculated even if $a+h$ is restricted to only rational values.

I think it's worth noting that the fact that $\mathbb Q$ is totally disconnected might give the wrong impression. The above definition only fails when fed *isolated* points - that is points with no other points in the domain in an open neighborhood. In the language of topology, we could say points such that $\{x\}$ is open in the domain of the function. Whether or not the domain is connected it somewhat irrelevant. So, you can't use this definition of for a function defined only on $\mathbb Z$ where every point is isolated. But it works fine on any dense subset of $\mathbb R$, like $\mathbb Q$. Another similar thing to think about is that not all function $f:\mathbb Q\rightarrow\mathbb R$ are continuous, despite $\mathbb Q$ being totally disconnected.

We might avoid using such a derivative as one might notice that a lot of theorems (e.g. the fundamental theorem of calculus) really do need conditions like "$f:\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R$ is everywhere differentiable" which can't be replaced by $f:A\rightarrow\mathbb R$ being differentiable everywhere *in its domain*.

Comment: @EricWofsey Whoops; I should know better than that. I have removed the incorrect material.

Comment: I still think its a good idea to look into these area regardless of the issues it brings to other theorems. Besides it further shows that mathematical theorems, in general, can't apply to all equations.

Comment: @MiloBrandt: Thank you for the answer (+1). What sound strange to me is the fact that a differentiable function is also continuous. So, as an example, the Dirichlet function, usually cited as example of nowhere continuous function, becomes a continuous and differentiable function if its domain is restricted to the rational numbers. I have never seen such a thing in any book  o any place!

Comment: @EmilioNovati Well, over $\mathbb Q$, the Dirichlet function is a constant function $1$ - so we've forgotten everything bad about it. More concerning are functions like $$f(x)=\begin{cases}0&\text{if }x<\sqrt{2}\\1&\text{if }x>\sqrt{2}\end{cases}$$ becomes differentiable and continuous, but can't be extended even continuously to $\mathbb R$. I'd imagine you can come up with worse behaved examples than that. There's also functions like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function) where a dense domain can be chosen where the derivative is always $0$, yet the function isn't constant.

Comment: @MiloBrandt If I took the complex derivative from $\left(-2\right)^x$ since $(-2)^x=\exp (\log (-2)x)= \exp ((\pi i+\log 2)x )$ and the derivative is ${\left({\pi}{i}+\ln(2)\right)}{e}^{{\pi}*{i}+\ln{(2)}}={\left({-1}\right)}^{x}{‌​2^x}\left({\pi}*{i}+\ln{(2)}\right)$ how can I convert this into a real equation?

Comment: @Arbuja I don't understand the question; $(-2)^x$ as you define it is complex valued. What do you mean "convert it into a real equation"?

Comment: Can you convert the complex derivative into an equation  that can have output which are real numbers with an $0i$ value in $a+{b}{i}$.

Comment: @Arbuja No, you can't. Being real is an intrinsic property of a number, and the derivative $(-1)^x2^x(\pi i + \log(2))$ that you list is, in general, not real. No amount of simplification will change this. Moreover, the number $(-2)^x$ is complex as you define it (it sweeps a spiral in the complex plane) so we would expect its change over time to be real.

Comment: @MiloBrandt Thank You. My professor advised going after complex analysis for these kind of limits but I had a feeling that this would not help define a real functioned derivative.

Comment: Good answer (+1). In physics, there is no measurable difference between rationals and irrationals and calculus with its limits originally comes from there, so ..

Comment: @MiloBrandt I gave you the bounty because you gave me a general approach and clarified my doubts. I will look deeper into this field....

Comment: The rationals are connected, at least according to a definition due to Cantor, so they are Cantor connected, also called [uniformly connected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniformly_connected_space) : For every $p,q$, for every $\varepsilon>0$ there is $n$ and a finite sequence $p_0,p_1,..,p_n$ with $p=p_0$, $q=p_n$, and $d(p_{k-1},p_k)<\varepsilon$ for all $k=1,..,n$. @HandeBruijn

Answer (score 0):

*This is not an answer but this could lead to an answer*

Taking the definition of a limit....
$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$

I found that there can be a derivative of $(-2)^x$ but only if $h\to0$ in a way that the numerator is even and the denominator is odd (even/odd). Such as $h\to\frac{2}{5}\to\frac{2}{101}\to\frac{2}{1000001}\to0$.

This is because using odd numerators and denominators (odd/odd) will result in the derivative diverging to $\infty$.

This is because for $(-2)^x$ the output is negative when x is (odd/odd) or positive when x is (even/odd).

For example $(-2)^{-1/15}=-.954841$ and $(-2)^{12/71}=1.124289$, which means.
$$(-2)^x=\begin{cases} 2^x & s=\left\{ {2n\over 2m+1}\ |\ n, m \in \Bbb Z\right\}\frac{\text{even integer}}{\text{odd integer}}\\ -\left(2^x\right) & s=\left\{ {2n+1\over 2m+1}\ |\ n, m \in \Bbb Z\right\}\frac{\text{odd integer}}{\text{odd integer}}\ \\ \text{undefined} & s=\left\{ {2n+1\over 2m}\ |\ n, m \in \Bbb Z\right\}\frac{\text{odd integer}}{\text{even integer}} \end{cases} $$

So then when we apply the formal definition of $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ where $f(x)=\left({-2}\right)^{x}$ 
$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{(-2)^{x+h}-(-2)^x}{h}$$

First if $h=\text{odd}/\text{even}$ such as $1/2$ and we take $x$ as $odd/odd$ or $x=1/3$ then $f(x)$ is already undefined. This means the entire limit is undefined. Now to get $f(x+h)$ we must get $x+h$ which is $5/6$ which means $f(x+h)$ is also undefined whenver $h$=odd/even. Thus...

$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{(-2)^{x+h}-(-2)^x}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{-2^{x+h}-2^x}{h}$$
$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{(-2)^{x+h}-(-2)^x}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\text{undefined}-\text{undefined}}{h}$$
$$\text{Limit does not exist}$$

Now if $h=\text{odd}/\text{odd}$ for example $h=1/3$ and let $x$ be (even/odd) fraction like $x=2/3$. So $f(x)=\left({2^x}\right)$; however $x+h=1$. This shows  under these conditions $x+h$ will always be (odd/odd) and thus $f(x+h)=-\left(2^{x+h}\right)$

So then when x is odd/odd the limit will be $$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{(-2)^{x+h}-(-2)^x}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{-2^{x+h}-2^x}{h}$$
$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\left(\left({-{2}^{h}-1}\right)*{{2}^{x}}\right)}{h}\approx$$
$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{-2\left(2\right)^{x}}{h}=$$ 
$$\lim_{h\to{0}}\frac{1}{h}*{-2\left(2\right)^{x}}$$
Now since$-2({2})^x$ is always postive we have to analyze $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{1}{h}$. Since that part of the limit does not exist there is no derivative.

$$\text{Limit Does Not Exist}$$

If $h=\text{odd}/\text{odd}$ for example $h=1/3$ but $x$ is (odd/odd) fraction like $x=1/5$. So $f(x)=-\left(2^x\right)$; however, $x+h=\frac{8}{15}$. This shows that under these conditions $x+h$ is always (even/odd) so $f(x+h)=2^{x+h}$. 
$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{(-2)^{x+h}-(-2)^x}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{2^{x+h}+2^x}{h}$$
$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\left(2^{h}+1\right)\left({2^x}\right)}{h}\approx$$
$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{2\left({2}^{x}\right)}{h}=$$
$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{1}{h}*2\left({2}^{x}\right)$$

Since $2\left({2}\right)^{x}$ is always positive but also has $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{1}{h}$ with a limit that does not exist there no derivative.

$$\text{Limit Does Not Exist}$$

But if $h=\text{even}/\text{odd}=2/3$ and $x=\text{odd}/{\text{odd}}=1/3$ then $f(x)=-\left(2^x\right)$. Since $x+h=3/3$, under these conditions, $x+h$ is always (odd/odd) and so $f(x+h)=-\left(2^{x+h}\right)$.
$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{(-2)^{x+h}-(-2)^x}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{-2^{x+h}+2^{x}}{h}=-\ln{(2)}{2^{x}}\to\text{For x=odd/odd}$$

And if $h=\text{even}/\text{odd}=2/3$ and $x=\text{even}/{\text{odd}}=2/3$ then $f(x)=2^x$. Since $x+h=4/3$, under these conditions, $x+h$ is always (even/odd) and thus $f(x+h)=2^{x+h}$.
$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{(-2)^{x+h}-(-2)^x}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{2^{x+h}-2^x}{h}=\ln{(2)}{2^x}\to\text{For x=even/odd}$$

$$\frac{d}{dx}(-2)^x=\begin{cases} \ln(2)2^x & s=\left\{ {2n\over 2m+1}\ |\ n, m \in \Bbb Z\right\}\frac{\text{even integer}}{\text{odd integer}}\\ -\ln(2)2^x & s=\left\{ {2n+1\over 2m+1}\ |\ n, m \in \Bbb Z\right\}\frac{\text{odd integer}}{\text{odd integer}}\end{cases}=\text{Limit does not exist}$$

According to what I have heard from mathematicians it is possible to define a derivative at cluster points. However for the defined cluster points of each group must have the same limit.

Take $\lim_{x\to\infty}\left({-1}^{x}\right)$ for example. It ossilates between $-1,1,-1,1$ and cannot exist. If I choose (even/odd) for $x\to\infty$ ($2/3\to2000/3\to200000/3$) then the only get $1$ but if I choose (odd/odd) for $x\to\infty$ ($1/3\to10/3\to10000/3$) then I only get $-1$. Thus all sequences for defined intervals of values that approaches some value must have the same limit.

Thus for $\left({-2}\right)^{x}$ the derivative must not exist. However if we instead took $|\left({-2}\right)^{x}|$ then the derivative would be $\ln{\left(2\right)}|\left(-2\right)^{x}|$. Infact when you put the absolute value the derivative satisfies the mean value theorem and rolles theorem.

Comment: this answer makes no sense to me. First thing, in the definition of derivative, you need $\lim_{h\to0}$, not $\lim_{x\to0}$. Next I do not see how you get that $\infty$ or $-\infty$ as the values of the limit. Don't know if this could make an "official" answer, being posted it is official, I would say, but it does not seem clear or correct. Also, you copied the same answer you made to another question, don't even see how it is relevant here. The function $f(x)=x\sin\dfrac1x$ for $x\not=0$, $f(0)=0$ is not differentiable at $0$ even if the limit exists picking a suitable sequence of $x$'s

Comment: @Mikro $x\sin{\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}$ is undefined at x=0 but $\left({-2}\right)^{x}$ is undefined for $x=\frac{m}{2k}$ where $m$ and $2k$ are integers. For example, $x=\frac{1}{2}$, $\frac{1}{20}$, \frac{3}{42}.

Comment: The mere fact that $x\sin\dfrac1x$ is undefined at $0$ does not make the function $f$ from my previous comment undefined, we have $f(0)=0$ as specified there. I would suggest you think things over more carefully.

Comment: I am still editing. Why did I get -1. I was only trying to help one find the answer.

Comment: @Mirko I made edits to my post. I apologize and please let me know if there is other issues.

Comment: I don't know why you got -1, I didn't vote either way. I may take a look again later if I have time, my impression was that when you take limit you should not make any special assumptions about the sequence of x's, the limit should exist and be the same regardless of different choices of sequences. I think that in what you had before one limit was obtained for one sequence, but this did would not imply that the limit exist, as another value of the limit would be obtained for a different sequence of x's. Cannot say much of the current version, may took a look later if I have time.

Comment: I need someone to check if this is the derivative.

Comment: @Mirko Do you have time right now?

Comment: @Mirko Despite the different choices of sequences the sequence does approach zero. For the even/odd or $\frac{2n}{2m+1}$ ,in particular, the undefined areas can be ignored.

Comment: I do not seem to be able to follow some of your basic algebra.For example, $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\left(\left({-{2}^{h}-1}\right)*{-{2}^{x}}\right)}{h}$ do you mean $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\left({-{2}^{h}-1}\right)*{(-{2}^{x}})}{h}$? Then when you factor, shouldn't you get $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\left(\left({-{2}^{h}+1}\right)*{-{2}^{x}}\right)}{h}$? Or rather, it seems you didn't even start correctly, like $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{-2^{x+h}-2^x}{h}$ and $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{2^{x+h}+2^x}{h}$ should be, $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{2^{x+h}-2^x}{h}$. Don't try to get the answer you want to, rather follow the correct math rules

Comment: I read your answer one more time and I think I see what you are trying to do.So some of your minuses are right but I think $\frac{(({-{2}^{h}-1})*{-{2}^{x}})}{h}$ should be $\frac{({{2}^{h}+1})*({-{2}^{x}})}{h}$.If $\mathbb Q$ is your domain then what you do proves the derivative does not exist as the limit is not supposed to depend on the particular choice that you let $h\to0$.The case when both $x$ and $h$ are of the form even/odd could be made formally correct by postulating that the domain is only those rationals of the form even/odd but then you are really working with $2^x$, not $(-2)^x$

Comment: @Mirko Perhaps someone should add for $h$ a limit should exist regardless of what type of numbers you use. I have not seen this in the definition of derivatives. How are sure that this is indeed the case?

Comment: it is not about the definition of derivative, it is about the definition of a limit. What definitions of a limit have you seen? Does any of them allow you to pick "nice" values with which $h\to0$? No! What is the limit of the sequence $1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,...$. Is it $1$, is it $0$, or is it the case that the limit dies not exist?

Comment: see https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Limit_of_Function_by_Convergent_Sequences and http://mathoverflow.net/questions/105920/advantages-of-the-sequence-definition-of-limits and http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/~john/analysis/Lectures/L12.html The reason you may have not seen this, is that the epsilon-delta definition of limit is most often found in many books, and the sequential definition is rarely seen (depending on which part of the world you study), which is an omission. Perhaps you have seen it, but need more practice, read your answer again keep in mind the definition of limit with sequences

Comment: @Mirko If you could understand it just hurts a bit that this and other kinds of derivatives cannot exist. You are right but I still think some of the other users should check with you.

Comment: @Mirko Milo Brandt said that such a derivative can exist and does not have to have the same limit everywhere. For example this derivative doesn't not have to differentiable at an undefined points of even/odd where $h\to\frac{\text{odd}}{\text{even}}\to0$ does not exist. Also he says defining the derivative is possible even if  $h\to\frac{\text{odd}}{\text{odd}}\to0$ goes to $\infty$  and $h\to\frac{\text{even}}{\text{odd}}\to0$ goes to $\ln{(2)}{\left(-2\right)^x}$.

Comment: Arbuja, I do not see any such comment here made by @MiloBrandt Also, I do not see why you expect him/her to spend time to decide whether what you or I say makes sense. If you are in doubt that what you say makes sense, then go over it more carefully. I already have provided plenty of detailed comments. Math truth is not about voting, and how many people say what is right, you ought to be able to convince yourself, once given enough hints, without bugging others over and over.