# About the derivative of a function defined on rational numbers

Tags: derivatives, functional-equations

I have found this problem:

> Let $f : \mathbb{Q} → \mathbb{R}$ with property: $$|f(x) − f(y)| \le (x − y)^2 \tag1$$ for all $x, y \in \mathbb{Q}$. Prove $f$ is constant.

---

My idea is to consider the formal derivative of $f$ like this:

$$f'(x) = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac {f(x + h) - f(x)}{h}, h \in \mathbb{Q} $$

Using (1) it's easy to prove the limit exists and is equals $0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{Q}$. So $f$ has derivative and $f'(x)=0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{Q}$. It follows that $f$ is constant.

Unfortunately, it's not that simple because: $$f'\equiv 0 \implies \ f  \ constant \tag 2$$ is a consequence of  [Mean Value Theorem](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Mean_Value_Theorem) which is valid only on real intervals.

> **My question:** is (2) valid for $f: \mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$?
>
> **Obs.** I don't need a proof for the problem.

Comment: Is $f$ even continuous?

Comment: Hard to apply real analytic methods to $\mathbb Q$.  More simply, though:  to see that, say $f(0)=f(1)$ note that $|f(0)-f(1)|=|f(0)-f(.5)+f(.5)-f(1)|≤|f(0)-f(.5)|+|f(.5)-f(1)|≤\frac 12$ and so on, constantly dividing each subinterval by $2$.

Comment: As an example of the difficulty in using real analytic methods, consider the function $g:\mathbb Q\to \mathbb R$ defined by $g(x)=0$ when $x<\pi$ and $g(x)=1$ when $x>\pi$.  That has derivative $0$ everywhere (as it is locally constant) but it is not a constant.

Comment: @lulu Your counter-example is very good, so (2) is not valid on rationals.

Comment: Right.  As you pointed out, you can define the derivative of functions on $\mathbb Q$ but you really don't get to keep much of the geometry.  Gets better if you require [absolute continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity).

Comment: @lulu Can you add the counter-example to your answer for me to accept it, please?

Comment: Just added it.  If you are interested in pathological examples, you might also want to take a look at the [Cantor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function).

Comment: This has been asked multiple times, under the more general form that if $$f(x)-f(y)|\leqslant c\cdot|x-y|^a$$ for every $(x,y)$, for some finite $c$ and some $a>1$, then $f$ is constant.

Comment: @Did I'm only interested in (2), not the problem

Comment: Perhaps $f'(x)=\lim_{h\to x}\frac{f(x)-f(h)}{x-h}$ is desired.

Comment: @SimpleArt It's the same thing.

Comment: @EugenCovaci Where did you find this? This could help me with the following question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1505310/we-can-define-the-derivative-of-a-function-whose-domain-is-a-subset-of-rational?rq=1

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The desired version of the Mean Value Theorem is not generally true for functions $g:\mathbb Q\to \mathbb R$.  To see that consider the function:  $$g(x) =
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if $x<\pi$} \\
1, & \text{if $x>\pi$}
\end{cases}$$

That function has derivative $0$ everywhere (as it is locally constant) but it is not a constant.

To your problem:

We have $$|f(x)-f(y)|=|f(x)-f\left(\frac {x+y}2\right)+f\left(\frac {x+y}2\right)-f(y)|≤|f(x)-f\left(\frac {x+y}2\right)|+|f\left(\frac {x+y}2\right)-f(y)|$$ $$≤\frac {(x-y)^2}2$$

Repeat this using the stronger estimate to see that $$|f(x)-f(y)|≤\frac {(x-y)^2}4$$  and iterate to see that ($\forall n\in \mathbb N$) $$|f(x)-f(y)|≤\frac {(x-y)^2}{2^n}$$

And as $n\to \infty$ we see that $f(x)=f(y)$.

Comment: The g function from your counter-example is continuous but not uniform continuous. If I add the uniform continuous condition does (2) become true?

Comment: You really need absolute continuity, which is stronger.  The [Cantor Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function) is uniformly continuous and has derivative 0 off a set of measure $0$, but it is not absolutely continuous.