# Derivative of higher order

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Suppose that we have a function $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ that is differentiable only  in $x=1,1/2, 1/3, 1/4, ..., 1/n$ and in $x=0$.
So a new function $f':\mathcal{A} \to\mathbb{R}$ arises, where $\mathcal{A}=\{0\}\cup \left\{\frac{1}{n} \right\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$.

Can I say that:

$$\lim_{\mathcal{A}\ni x \to 0}\frac{f'(x)-f'(0)}{x-0}$$

is the *second derivative of the function $f$ in $x=0$*?
Or does the second derivative, to be defined as such, requires the existence of the first derivative in a neighborhood of $0$ of the type $[0, a]$, with $0<a\leq 1$?

Comment: The second derivative, just as the first derivative and any order one, is a *limit*: you need the function to be divided in a complete neighborhood of the point to which $\;x\;$ tends...and you don't have it here, not even at zero.

Comment: In order for the limit to make sense, it is sufficient that $x = 0$ is a limit point for the domain of $f '(x)$, and $x=0$ is a limit point for $\mathcal{A}$.

Comment: That, I think, is false. Within the real numbers we need a continuum to do limits. You don't have it here.

Comment: @Nameless, considering *@DonAntonio comment, are you defining the derivative as the right limit only of the increment ratio ?

Comment: @DonAntonio No, It’s not true. In general, a limit doesn’t require ‘continuum’, but only a limit point.

Comment: I think you can say that. But I'd include the set $A$ somehow. Maybe like this: $...$ is the second derivative of $f$ at $x=0$ on the set $A$.

Comment: @Botond Yes, I think that this is the best way.

Comment: @Nameless Ok, you seem to know better about real analysis than I do. Do it as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

The *definition* of the derivative is
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}$$
and by *definition* of the limit this is
$$\forall\epsilon>0\,\exists\delta>0\;|\;\left|x\right|<\delta\;\Rightarrow\left|\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}-L\right|<\epsilon$$
The definition most definitely requires *all* $\left|x\right|<\delta$ to work, that is to say, at the very least $f$ needs to exist in a neighbourhood $\left(-\delta,+\delta\right)$.

The right one-sided derivative still needs a neighbourhood of the form $\left[0,\delta\right)$ to work.

Comment: Sorry if I return to this point, but in the book V. Zorich Mathematical Analysis 1, the definition of the derivative of a function $f:E\subset \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ in a point $a\in E$ that is a limit point for $E$, is:

$$\lim_{E \ni x\to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}.$$

So, nowhere Zorich says that $E$ is an interval, it can be a generic set with $a$ as limit point and such that $a\in E$.

Comment: I also found this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1505310/we-can-define-the-derivative-of-a-function-whose-domain-is-a-subset-of-rational?rq=1

Comment: @obscu Good answer. +1 Yet the OP thinks he knows better and one doesn't need continuum to work out this in real analysis. Fine.

Comment: @DonAntonio +1. Of course you can *change* the definition of the derivative if you want, but then you are no longer doing **real analysis**. You can say whatever functions you want satisfy your version of differentiability, but theorems of real analysis no longer apply. For example, in the other question you linked, *you can't use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus any more*.

Comment: @obscurans Exactly my point. In the link given by the OP it is aksed exactly something like this: to define the limit notion for element in $\;\Bbb Q\;$ and not in $\;\Bbb R\;$ ...and this already would produce some rather interesting results, as having a limit equal to an element not in $\;\Bbb Q\;$, for example. Why that author Zorich defines what he does the way he does is beyond my understanding. Perhaps later I'll take a peek to his book.

Comment: Real analysis has such heavy implict use of the completeness of the field that I really don't have any sense what those results look like. A limit that isn't in the field... just *doesn't exist*. The same way $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{1}{x}$ DNE, we don't pretend we'll extend to the Riemann sphere.